# nestjs-i18n blocks my local passport strategy

Tags: nestjs, nestjs-i18n

I am working with nestjs. I implemented `i18n` from the following tutorial available on the `[nestjs-i18][1]n`

To my surprise when I add the following configurations in the app module it messes up with my passport local strategy.

```
imports: [
    I18nModule.forRoot({
      fallbackLanguage: 'en',
      parser: I18nJsonParser,
      parserOptions: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, '/i18n/'),
      },
    }),
  ],
```

when I try to login it gives the following error:

> Unknown authentication strategy "local"

My local passport strategy works fine if I remove the `i18n` configurations from the app module. I cannot understand the link between these two.
could somebody please let me know how these two are interconnected?

Comment: Do you inject anything from i18n into the strategy?